# Using a visual "proof" to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac 34 \right)^n =1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, proof-without-words

The "proof without words" that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac 12 \right)^n =1$ is fairly well known:

[image]

But why can't we apply the exact same logic to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac 34 \right)^n$ or any other infinite sum of a fraction?

[image]

(apologies for the giant images)

Comment: The area showing $\frac{9}{16}$ isn't really equal to $\frac{9}{16}$.  It is equal to $\frac{3}{16}$.  You have proven that $\frac{3}{4}\sum_{r=0}^\infty\,\frac{1}{4^r}=1$ by this figure.

Comment: And $\sum_0^\infty (3/4)^k = 4$, right?

Comment: In the first diagram rectangles are disjoint while in the second they overlap. The sum $3/4+9/16+27/64+\ldots$ gives 3, so you should start from a rectangle having area 3.

Comment: @Raffaele : The L-shaped regions whose areas are supposed to be reported in the second picture do not overlap.  The problem is that their areas are $3/4,\ 3/16,\ 3/64,\ldots$ instead of $3/4,\ 9/16,\ 27/64,\ldots$. ${}\qquad{}$